# Geolocation with Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator

I want to develop an application with Appcelerator where I have a fleet of bikes, all with smartphone. I want to know the location of each one. Can someone give me a help by using localization by smartphone android GPS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get it periodically, so you can track where the bikes are at a given moment...

What you would need is to use Titanium Geolocation. you can read about it here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation

and call getCurrentPosition method (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-method-getCurrentPosition) that accepts a callback function with the location.

Inside that callback function send the information to your server (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-method-createHTTPClient)

and just call that function every X interval you with using a setInterval or setTimeout.

keep in mind that the app will need to run in order for it to keep working, unless you write an android service (not possible on iOS).

Comment: in ios you can use [Background Services](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services) it will run in background and can be used to update the location.

Comment: @Dragon iOS background services only go into play when the app goes to the background (it does not work when the app is in the foreground). And the background service can't work for more than 10 minutes - it will shutdown after 10 minutes or if the system needs the resources - so it's not something to rely on.

Comment: while the app is in foreground it is easy to update user's location to server but as soon as app goes in background, you can use background services. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) is an excellent demonstration.
Also the link in my previous comment is the background service API for above 3.2.0 and i think it will not stop in 10 minutes unlike its predecessor.

Comment: @Dragon - as I mentioned in my post - iOS limits the time and resources of background services.

Comment: Grateful to all. First I would like to have a good example for android. My main problem is that the examples that I took, the latitude and longitude positions do not match what I saw in the original map. When I try to retrace a route positions are totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do like this:

first create service.js under android folder, and there write something like:

```
startSendigGpsPositions();

function startSendingGpsPosition(){
     Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
         var postData = {};
         postData["localizationSystems"] = [];
         postData["localizationSystems"].push({
                    "localizationSystem_id":"gps",
                    "entries":[ {
                              "lat": e.coords.latitude,
                              "lon": e.coords.longitude,
                              "accuracy": e.coords.accuracy
                    } ]
                });
        callHttpFunction(postData, {
            onSuccess: function(){
               //if needed you can set a timeout so the battery does not die immediately 
               setTimeOut(function(){
                  startSendingGpsPosition();
               }, 1000)
            },
            onError: function(){
              // decide if you want to show the error to the user or just ignore it and recall startSendingGpsPosition
            }
        })
     });
}


function callHttpFunction(postData, callback){
     var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient(); 

     xhr.open(POST, url);

     xhr.onload = function(e) { 
         var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
         callback.onSuccess(res);
     };

     xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
        var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
        callback.onError(res);
     };

     if (Titanium.Network.online) { 
        xhr.send(postData);
     } else { 
        if (callback.error) { callback.onError(); }
     };
}
```

From index.js you call it like this:

```
function startService(){
    var intent = Ti.Android.createServiceIntent({
       url : 'service.js'
    });


    if(!Ti.Android.isServiceRunning(intent)){
       Ti.Android.startService(intent);
    } 
}
```

Another way is to create a  native module where you use onLocationChanged function, so any time your location will change it will give you back the geo point without having to ask any 1 second for the gps position. This is how it should look like:

```
LocationListener locationListener  = null;
...
locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location gpsLocation) { 
            HashMap<String , String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            HashMap<String , String> container = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("success", "true");
            container.put("latitude", ""+gpsLocation.getLatitude());
            container.put("longitude", ""+gpsLocation.getLongitude());
            container.put("accuracy", ""+gpsLocation.getAccuracy());
            container.put("altitude", ""+gpsLocation.getAltitude());
            container.put("provider", ""+gpsLocation.getProvider());
            container.put("speed", ""+gpsLocation.getSpeed());
            map.put("container", (new JSONObject(container)).toString());

            callbackLocation.call(getKrollObject(), map);
        }
    };
```

Once you have the data in the callback you can do the http request from javascript :)

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend NOT using Titanium, especially if you plan to make another App. I started with Titanium and although I found Javascript straightforward and enjoyable, the framework is severely limiting when you start trying to do more advanced things. With native you have much greater control, and it's very much worth the hump of learning.

Comment: Everything that you can do with Native can be done by Titanium.And development with Titanium is fast compared to Native.

Comment: @Dragon True, development is very fast. Especially when you are creating a simple application that only displays views of information. But I found it limiting when I dove into more advanced topics, disappointed each time I searched the API.